# Способы конкретизации типа в generic классах

Tags: c#, generics, преобразование-типов, c#-7.0

Есть класс

```
public class Param<T>
{
    public T Value { get; protected set; }

    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static T GetInstance(byte[] bytes)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Он инкапсулирует значение параметра (параметр может быть *любого значимого типа*, но реально будет `uint`, `float` и `double`). В методе `GetBytes` нужно сделать как-то так:

```
public byte[] GetBytes()
{
    return BitConverter.GetBytes(Value);
}
```

Аналогично нужно сделать и в методе `GetInstance`. Понятно, что компилятор такое не пропустит, потому что он пока ничего не знает о типе T. 
Вот, как я планирую решить эту проблему:

```
public byte[] GetBytes()
{
    switch (Value)
    {
        case uint ui:
            return BitConverter.GetBytes(ui);
        case float f:
            return BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
        case double d:
            return BitConverter.GetBytes(d);
        default:
            throw new Exception();
    }            
}
```

Но эта фича доступна только начиная с C# 7.1. Как можно по-другому обходить все возможные варианты типа? Какой вариант наиболее предпочтителен? Во что разворачивается этот новомодный switch-case?

Comment: Что мешает включить C#7.1? Либо пишите через `if`/словарь

Comment: А разворачивается это в простой каст с последующим if: [ссылка](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABADAAmwEYBuAWAChsBmQgJnwGF8Bvfd/Sjw24AT3gBtALr4A4nBgAhAXCgAKAPbAAVnADGMfADcAlFw4sD3dlADuASxjqAFvnl7jJoxRNv866HHwBXCwDstPxAndxNsAHZ8KStGRX9tRHgEADoJaVkFP11yVzCOTyhvADMAG0UILWKQvPzwqJiYOISkxDTJGXgFYpzQ90LvFEUfYFLBmrq3SOjY+MSEZPaMrvkUXtr8lDhiiB9SmAnJ7hgbBEUzfH84C4BRAA91OAAHGAt4+XWwgF8jpy/KL5AA===)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ничего, в принципе. Мне просто интересно, как до этого правильно было конкретизировать тип. Через if? Видел способ, использующий `Type.GetTypeCode()`. Много разных способов, но что лучше?

Comment: Если действительно будет только три типа, то сделайте три перегрузки метода с каждым типом и не нужно никаких обобщений, кастов и т. п.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а как тогда хранить значение в классе `Param`? Ведь здесь это самое главное. И метод GetBytes() вообще не принимает никаких аргументов, прошу заметить.

Comment: Сделайте три класса: UintParam, FloatParam, DoubleParam. А главное, зачем вообще нужна эта оболочка над BitConverter'ом?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вот у меня до этого тоже было такое решение. Просто у меня есть класс, условно назовем его `Info` и у него есть куча свойств. И я бы хотел иметь возможность работать с ними как со списком, чтобы не приходилось каждому свойству присваивать значение в отдельной строке, а просто в цикле по каждому параметру дать ему значение. Я могу, конечно, каждый раз в отдельной строчке работать с конкретным свойством, но не уверен, что это лучшее решение.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov у класса `Info` есть свой метод `GetBytes()`, который берет по очереди каждое свойство, вызывает у него `GetBytes()`  и добавляет в выходной массив.